# EJB3 how to make sure things happen before a bean get deleted

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, stateful-session-bean

Suppose I let my customer reserve seats on a plane using Stateful Session Bean. If the client explicitly calls my Remove method, all of his reservations will be cancelled and the bean is removed afterward.

However, in case the client is idle for some time and the Bean get passivated, if the Bean times out while being passivated, it would be deleted without calling any of my functions. Hence, I'd be very grateful if someone could show me how I can make sure that the reservations would be cancelled if the bean get deleted. If I use the @PreDestroy annotation, will it solve this problem?

Best regards,
James Tran

Comment: Well, it seems to me that @PreDestroy will not solve this problem. Suppose the state of A is passivated and B is currently active on the Stateful bean, if @PreDestroy function is called, only B's reservations will be cancelled. Am I right?

Comment: not really, there is always one (stateful) bean instance per client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite possible for the `@PreDestroy` method to not be invoked. The EJB 3.1 specification, explicitly states this:

> **4.6.3 Missed PreDestroy Calls**
>
> The Bean Provider cannot assume that the container will always invoke
>   the PreDestroy lifecycle callback interceptor method(s) (or ejbRemove
>   method) for a session bean instance. The following scenarios result in
>   the PreDestroy lifecycle callback interceptor method(s) not being
>   called for an instance:
>
> • A crash of the EJB container.
>
> • A system exception thrown from the instance’s method to the container.
>
> • **A timeout of client inactivity while the instance is in the passive state.** The timeout is specified by the Deployer in an EJB container implementation-specific way.

The specification also details how resources may be removed if the `@PreDestroy` method is not invoked in such scenarios:

> For example, if a shopping cart component is implemented as a session
>   bean, and the session bean stores the shopping cart content in a
>   database, the application should provide a program that runs
>   periodically and removes “abandoned” shopping carts from the database.

In your case, it would depend on how you are storing the state of your reservations. If they are persisted in the database, then I would suggest employing the same approach as mandated in the specification. You could use the EJB Timer service, to perform this activity periodically, or use a scheduler like Quartz. Note, that it is imperative to distinguish between the contents of passivated session bean instances that no longer exist, and those that will be made ready once again.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'd be very grateful if you could help me with another small question. In case the bean is deleted while being passivated, the client's session still have a reference to the deleted bean. Could you please show me how I can detect that the bean has been deleted?

Comment: Your question - `Could you please show me how I can detect that the bean has been deleted?` implies that it is possible to detect, when in fact it is impossible for a client to do so. The stateful session bean is created and managed by the container. The client only has a proxy reference to it. If you need to handle this scenario, you must catch the `NoSuchEJBException` exception that could *possibly be thrown* on every method invocation, and attempt to create a new instance of the bean.

Answer (score 1):

A passivated bean will get destroyed on timeout and hence any method annotated with `@PreDestroy` will do what you are looking for.

While A is active, A's instance of the Stateful bean will not be shared with B until A's instance is destroyed. See [the diagram](http://what-when-how.com/enterprise-javabeans-3/stateful-session-beans-ejb-3/) on this article for further reading

Comment: Thanks a lot. The article is really useful =).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should. The method annotated with `@PreDestroy` will be called prior to  bean removal (even if i times-out in the passivated state)

Comment: Thanks for your reply =). I have another question. In the book "Learn to program EJB 3.0", the author wrote that:

    "The passivated session bean instance is not destroyed and may be used to service a different client's request."

Does it mean that 1 Stateful bean can hold several client's state (1 active and all other passivated)? Hence, when the bean @PreDestroy function is called, it can only perform actions on the current active state. I think I have some misunderstanding here, please correct me if I'm wrong.